# Java Functional Interface matches against methods with fewer input arguments

Tags: java

I wrote a function the other day which Intellij told me I could simplify. I have a functional interface with one method, which has 2 arguments. Its return type is the same as the first input argument.

Turns out that I can send in a referance to a method which only needs 1 argument (the last argument), as long as it returns the correct type. I tried switching the order of Type1 and Type2 arguments in the Functional Interface, but that did not work. I do not think that this should work. Can someone explain why it works or link me the documentation? I have not been able to find any information.

Working example

```
public class Testcase {

    private String string;

    @FunctionalInterface
    interface WithFunction<Type1, Type2> {
        Type1 apply(Type1 type1, Type2 type2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WithFunction<Testcase, String> withFunction = Testcase::withString;
        Testcase testcase = withFunction.apply(new Testcase(), "string");
        System.out.println(testcase.string);
    }

    public Testcase withString(String string) {
        this.string = string;
        return this;
    }

}
```

Comment: is it an error from intelliJ or does it actually compile, can you test that?

Comment: It does compile, It was just a helpful tip: I see you are using a lambda, would you like to use Testcase::withString instead?

Answer (score 3):

Your `public Testcase withString(String string)` method has two arguments: the first is implicit - the `Testcase` instance on which the method is called, and the second is explicit - a `String` argument.

Therefore the method reference `Testcase::withString` is assignable to a variable of type `WithFunction<Testcase, String>`.

When you call `withFunction.apply(new Testcase(), "string")`, a `Testcase` instance is created, and the `String` "string" is passed to the `withString(String string)` method of that instance.

Comment: Yes, I thought that was what is happening, but do you know where this implicit connection is made? Is there documentation of it somewhere? It's very useful, so I was wondering if maybe there are other such implicit connections i can make, and simplify other thing as well.

Comment: @Jani You can read any docs about method references. A method reference to a non static method has an implicit first argument which is the instance on which the method is called. That's about it.